# Why is this code looping infinitely?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write a program in JavaScript that generates 100 random numbers and checks the primality of each. The program does just that, except for some reason it doesn't stop at 100 and just loops infinitely. I'm sure I made some simple novice mistake, but for some reason I can't see it. Any advice?

My code:

```
function isPrime(n) {
    if (n < 2 || n % 1)
        return false;

    var r = Math.sqrt(n);

    for (i = 2; i <= r; i++)
        if (n % i === 0)
            return false;

    return true;
}

for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    var temp = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);

    if (isPrime(temp))
        console.log(temp + " is a prime number!");
    else
        console.log(temp + " is not a prime number.");
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

madox2 is correct that you should declare `i` in the for loop, however I think the reason the loop itself is infinite is because by only doing `i=0` in the loop, and then `for (i = 2; i <= r; i++)` in the function the loop calls, you are resetting `i` every iteration

You should change your code to declare `i` within the scope of both loops separately, like so:

```
function isPrime(n) {
    if (n < 2 || n % 1)
        return false;

    var r = Math.sqrt(n);

    for (var i = 2; i <= r; i++)
        if (n % i === 0)
            return false;

    return true;
}

for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    var temp = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);

    if (isPrime(temp))
        console.log(temp + " is a prime number!");
    else
        console.log(temp + " is not a prime number.");
}
```

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you! I'll be sure to remember this whenever I need to use i multiple times.

Comment: For the record, when you don't use `var`, your variables are assigned to the `window` scope. Also an angel loses its wings.

Comment: No problem! Remember to tick this answer as Accepted so future users know it worked!

Answer (score 4):

You need to declare `i` variable in for-loops:

```
(var i = 0; i < 100; i++) ...
```

otherwise it is defined in global scope and it is shared between for-loop and `isPrime` function.

Comment: Just fixed that, but it's still looping. In case it's relevant, I'm using Node.js to check the code.

Comment: @temporubato works for me. have you fixed it in both for-loops?